# Convert double foreach to LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
foreach (var lg in basket)
{
    foreach (var acc in lg.Accomodations)
    {
        if (acc.HotelID == h.ID)
        {
            hotel.SelectedInPreviousLeg = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to convert this double foreach to linq. Any suggestions?
So far i tried this, but there is a compile error.

```
var test = basket.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Accommodations, Any(y => y.HotelID == h.ID));
hotel.SelectedInPreviousLeg = (test != null) ? true : false;
```

Comment: `hotel.SelectedInPreviousLeg = basket.SelectMany(lg => lg.Accomodations).Any(acc => acc.HotelID == h.ID);`

Comment: Works great, thank you mr.Vogt.

Answer (score 1):

or, assuming classes are defined equivalently to

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Accomodation> Accomodations { get; set; }
    public bool SelectedInPreviousLeg {  get set; }
}

public class Accomodation
{
    public int HotelID { get; set; }
}
```

then you could do this:

```
foreach (var acc in
     from lg in basket
     from acc in lg.Accomodations
     where acc.HotelID == h.ID 
     select acc)
         hotel.SelectedInPreviousLeg = true;
```

... but that will iterate through all combinations, when you only need to find the first one that satisfies the condiditon, so you could do this, which will stop after finding the first one:

```
 hotel.SelectedInPreviousLeg = 
     basket
        .Any(b => b.Accomodations
        .Any(a => a.HotelID == h.ID));
```